# After ResizeObserver event

Tags: javascript, css

I have a resizeObserver (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) monitoring the change in size of a div. However, during the resize event I want to display the border of the div and then have it disappear after it finishes resizing.

To do this, I have a .tempBorder class which is to be added on the resize event:

Css:

```
.tempBorder {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
var chartResizer = document.getElementById('chartResizer');
    var chartResizerResizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
        chartResizer.classList.add("tempBorder");
    }
    ).observe(chartResizer);
```

But I can't remove the class using `chartResizer.classList.remove("tempBorder");` as there doesn't seem to be an event that gets triggered after the resize is completed than I can find.

I am aware that this might be deliberate as the after event would be triggered continuously during the resizing, so am wondering whether using `setTimeOut` in it instead is the better solution?

So something like this:

```
 var chartResizer = document.getElementById('chartResizer');
    var chartResizerResizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
        chartResizer.classList.add("tempBorder");
        myChart.resize();
        setTimeout(function(){
            chartResizer.classList.remove("tempBorder");
        }, 1000);
    }
    ).observe(chartResizer);
```

Do I have to do something like the second example or is there a more effective way to achieve what I want with an `after` event for `resizeObserver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call

```
chartResizer.classList.remove("tempBorder");
```

on `mouseup` event

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't think of the mouseup event. I'll give that a go now. Thanks.